# How to change the direction of a moving picture once it hits the corner of the screen

Tags: java, image, processing, collision

The image that I have is a top right arrow and I want it to change direction once it collides with the corner or the edges of the screen this way my arrow picture can face the direction it is going.

[image]

```
int x;
int y;
int xspeed;
int yspeed;
PImage dvd;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  x = 400;
  y = 100;
  dvd = loadImage("topright.png");
  xspeed = 10;
  yspeed = 10;
}

void draw() {
  background(50);
  image(dvd, x, y, 80, 60);
  x = x + xspeed;
  y = y + yspeed;
  if (x + 80 == width || x == 0) {
    xspeed = xspeed * -1;
  }
  if (y + 60 == height || y == 0) {
    yspeed = -yspeed;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have other predrawn icons?

Comment: I would consider using something more like `if (x + 80 >= width || x == 0) {` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by scaling the geometry with [`scale()`](https://processing.org/reference/scale_.html). The idea is to scale with (1, 1), (-1, 1), (1, -1) or (-1, -1) depending on the direction of movement.   First [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) the image by (-40, -40). Now the (0, 0) is in the center of the image. After that flip (`scale`) the image. Finally `translate` the image to its traget position:

```java
int x;
int y;
int xspeed;
int yspeed;
int scale_x = 1;
int scale_y = 1;
PImage dvd;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  x = 400;
  y = 100;
  dvd = loadImage("topright.png");
  xspeed = 10;
  yspeed = 10;
}

void draw() {
  background(50);
  
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x+40, y+40);
  scale(scale_x, scale_y);
  translate(-40, -40);
  image(dvd, 0, 0, 80, 60);
  popMatrix();
  
  x = x + xspeed;
  y = y + yspeed;
  if (x + 80 >= width) {
    xspeed *= -1;
    scale_x = -1;
  }
  else if (x <= 0) {
    xspeed *= -1;
    scale_x = 1;
  }
  if (y + 60 >= height) {
    yspeed *= -1;
    scale_y = -1;
  } else if (y + 60 == height || y == 0) {
    yspeed *= -1;
    scale_y = 1;
  }
}
```